# jquery - how can I check if the node is an element or text

Tags: jquery, parsing

I want to be able to identify when the first child of a text string is an element or a text node so for example:

I was thinking of doing: `$('<span>'+my_html_string+'</span>').children().is('*')`

But this doesn't always work.

1: The first child is text. some examples:

```
<span>some text<span> //works using above code
<div>here is some <span>text</span></div> //fails using above code
<pre>check out my text</pre> //works
```

2: the first child is any element, some examples:

```
<div><span>I am an element</span></div> //works
<span><div>first child div</div>understand?</span> //works
```

How can I detect if the very first item within an element is text or an element?

Comment: Trivially, `$(my_html_string).html().substr(0,1) == '<'` ?

Comment: @moonwave99: does the `html()` method always trim white-space? (I'm not challenging your suggestion, this really is just a question)

Comment: @DavidThomas just tried in the console, it does not ^^ - of course we can trim it with jQuery, but it starts becoming less naive this way.

Comment: @moonwave99 - yours is the only answer on the page currently which works.

Comment: The reason for this is that jQuery strips out the text before the element when using a HTML string

Comment: @Ash I dared to post it as an answer then : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive way:

```
$(my_html_string).html().substr(0,1) == '<'
```

Consider using [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to get rid of eventual whitespace.

Comment: The reason this answer works better than the above, in this particular use case, is that when using nodeType, any text preceding an element appears to be stripped by jQuery 

e.g : if the string is : 'text<span>moretext</span>' then this string returns a nodeType of 1

similarly if the string is '<div>content</div>' - this also returns a nodetype of 1.

Comment: Although the answer above says nothing as to the validity of the HTML string, for my particular use case this works.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using some plain JavaScript (albeit combined with jQuery for the iteration over the relevant nodes/elements). The following is untested, but I think gets the point across:

```
function firstChildIs(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        switch (el.firstChild.nodeType) {
            case 1:
            return 'Element is an element';
            break;
            case 2:
            return 'Element is an attribute node';
            break;
            case 3:
            return 'Element is a textNode';
            break;
            case 4:
            return 'Element is a CDATA section node';
            break;
            case 5:
            return 'Entity reference node';
            break;
            case 6:
            return 'entity node';
            break;
            case 7:
            return 'processing instruction node';
            break;
            case 8:
            return 'comment node';
            break;
            case 9:
            return 'document node';
            break;
            case 10:
            return 'document type node';
            break;
            case 11:
            return 'document fragment node';
            break;
            case 12:
            return 'document notation node';
            break;
            default:
            return 'Something horrible has probably happened...';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And call with:

```
$(elementSelector).each(
    function(){
        console.log(firstChildIs(this));
    });
```

Edited because I thought that using an array might be easier than using a switch:

```
function firstChildIs(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var nodetypes = ['element', 'attribute', 'text',
                         'CDATA section', 'entity reference',
                         'entity', 'processing instruction',
                         'comment', 'document', 'document type',
                         'document fragment', 'document notation'];
        return nodetypes[el.firstChild.nodeType - 1] || 'something really unexpected happened';
    }
}
```

Call in the same way as previously illustrated, and if you want to add the word 'node` do remember to add it to the value returned by the function.

It's also worth remembering that some (though I don't think *all*) browsers do report white-space (the newlines and tabs) between opening tags as being a text-node, so it's entirely possible that you'd have to trim the white-space before assessing the the `firstChild`'s node-type.

References:

- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType).

Comment: `return; break;` is redundant, no?

Comment: Yeah, it *is*, but...I always include a `break` with a switch. Just because. I know, that's a terrible reason, but it's just my way. =/

Comment: you must like carpal tunnel. ;p Also, how can `|| 'something really...` work when you're always going to get at least `' node'`? (_i'm not nit-picking, I promise. ;p_)

Comment: Always get `' node'`? I don't know *what* you mean, sir; all *I* saw was a gust of wind..! *cough* (*edited*)

Comment: And seriously, though: I appreciate the constructive criticism (I learned JavaScript more or less by accident, so I do (often/occasionally) do silly things and overlook something obvious), this way I actually learn what I'm doing wrong or when I'm doing something unnecessarily. So, honestly: thanks! =)

Comment: could save a bunch of redundant code turning `switch` cases into object or array

Comment: No worries. If you really _do_ appreciate the criticism I might also argue the `else` moot since you're first `if` is an immediate return. Either `if(el){return result;} return false;` or `if(!el)return; return result;`; And how does that go? _Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new. -Einstein_

Comment: @charlietfl: you're right; I was doing that a little before I saw your comment (or at least the [timestamp of my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14086957/4) suggests that was the case when compared to the time of your comment). Thanks, though. Good advice! =)

Comment: ws just a `DRY` thought... no biggy

Answer (score 1):

```
$('....').get(0).nodeType == 3 // first node is a text node
```

Something like that? use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the DOM element, and check against [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$("element_selector:first-child")[0].nodeType == 3`